# Cannot compile proper 32bit libzip library for android

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I cloned hg repository of libzip from here:
https://hg.nih.at/libzip/

I know there's a package of libzip for android but first I wanted to give it a try with original one because I wanted my future project operate with same version of library source in other platforms as far as I can manage.

I'm not very familiar with CMake build system,
So I borrowed necessary parameters from cmake_build_command.txt which was generated by Android Studio while building my test NDK project.

So, my batch file to execute cmake is like this:

```
rmdir /S /Q build
"C:\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe"^
 .^
 -H"D:\Project\External\libzip"^
 -B"D:\Project\External\libzip\build"^
 -G"Android Gradle - Ninja"^
 -D"ANDROID_ABI=x86"^
 -D"ANDROID_NDK=C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle"^
 -D"CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\Project\External\libzip\build"^
 -D"CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"^
 -D"CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe"^
 -D"CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake"^
 -D"ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-23"
cd build
C:\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe
```

And here's output:

```
D:\Project\External\libzip>"C:\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe" . -H"D:\Project\External\libzip" -B"D:\Project\External\libzip\build" -G"Android Gradle - Ninja" -D"ANDROID_ABI=x86" -D"ANDROID_NDK=C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle" -D"CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\Project\External\libzip\build" -D"CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" -D"CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe" -D"CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake" -D"ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-23"
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Looking for _chmod
-- Looking for _chmod - not found
-- Looking for _close
-- Looking for _close - not found
-- Looking for _dup
-- Looking for _dup - not found
-- Looking for _fdopen
-- Looking for _fdopen - not found
-- Looking for _fileno
-- Looking for _fileno - not found
-- Looking for _open
-- Looking for _open - not found
-- Looking for _setmode
-- Looking for _setmode - not found
-- Looking for _snprintf
-- Looking for _snprintf - not found
-- Looking for _strdup
-- Looking for _strdup - not found
-- Looking for _stricmp
-- Looking for _stricmp - not found
-- Looking for _strtoi64
-- Looking for _strtoi64 - not found
-- Looking for _strtoui64
-- Looking for _strtoui64 - not found
-- Looking for _umask
-- Looking for _umask - not found
-- Looking for _unlink
-- Looking for _unlink - not found
-- Looking for explict_bzero
-- Looking for explict_bzero - not found
-- Looking for explicit_memset
-- Looking for explicit_memset - not found
-- Looking for fileno
-- Looking for fileno - found
-- Looking for fseeko
-- Looking for fseeko - found
-- Looking for ftello
-- Looking for ftello - found
-- Looking for getprogname
-- Looking for getprogname - found
-- Looking for open
-- Looking for open - found
-- Looking for mkstemp
-- Looking for mkstemp - found
-- Looking for setmode
-- Looking for setmode - not found
-- Looking for snprintf
-- Looking for snprintf - found
-- Looking for strcasecmp
-- Looking for strcasecmp - found
-- Looking for strdup
-- Looking for strdup - found
-- Looking for stricmp
-- Looking for stricmp - not found
-- Looking for strtoll
-- Looking for strtoll - found
-- Looking for strtoull
-- Looking for strtoull - found
-- Looking for include file fts.h
-- Looking for include file fts.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdbool.h
-- Looking for include file stdbool.h - found
-- Looking for include file strings.h
-- Looking for include file strings.h - found
-- Looking for include file unistd.h
-- Looking for include file unistd.h - found
-- Looking for include file inttypes.h
-- Looking for include file inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdint.h
-- Looking for include file stdint.h - found
-- Looking for include file sys/types.h
-- Looking for include file sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of __int8
-- Check size of __int8 - failed
-- Check size of int8_t
-- Check size of int8_t - done
-- Check size of uint8_t
-- Check size of uint8_t - done
-- Check size of __int16
-- Check size of __int16 - failed
-- Check size of int16_t
-- Check size of int16_t - done
-- Check size of uint16_t
-- Check size of uint16_t - done
-- Check size of __int32
-- Check size of __int32 - failed
-- Check size of int32_t
-- Check size of int32_t - done
-- Check size of uint32_t
-- Check size of uint32_t - done
-- Check size of __int64
-- Check size of __int64 - failed
-- Check size of int64_t
-- Check size of int64_t - done
-- Check size of uint64_t
-- Check size of uint64_t - done
-- Check size of short
-- Check size of short - done
-- Check size of int
-- Check size of int - done
-- Check size of long
-- Check size of long - done
-- Check size of long long
-- Check size of long long - done
-- Check size of off_t
-- Check size of off_t - done
-- Check size of size_t
-- Check size of size_t - done
-- Check size of ssize_t
-- Check size of ssize_t - done
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Found ZLIB: C:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-23/arch-x86/usr/lib/libz.so (found version "1.2.3")
-- Could NOT find BZip2 (missing:  BZIP2_LIBRARIES BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Looking for getopt
-- Looking for getopt - found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Project/External/libzip/build

D:\Project\External\libzip>cd build

D:\Project\External\libzip\build>C:\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe
[133/133] Linking C executable regress\tryopen
```

And I linked this with my project:

```
include_directories( ../../../External/libzip/lib
                     ../../../External/libzip/build
                     )

target_link_libraries( native-lib

                       ${z-lib}
                       D:/Project/External/libzip/build/lib/libzip.a
                       )
```

And I build my ndk project with this gradle setup:

```
externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static"
                cppFlags "-std=c++14", "-frtti", "-fexceptions"
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86"
        }
```

Honestly I didn't expect it would be done this easily.
But surprisingly, it was successfully linked with my test NDK project and ran smoothly.
I could open my apk file with zip_open() and read contents of individual files with no problem.

But soon after I realized it wasn't the case for other ABIs.
In all other ABIs except my initial try, which was arm64-v8a, zip_open() returns NULL.
What I could inspect with debugger is parameters of zip_open() become all messy, string for apk path suddenly become "1" and all others are garbage too inside zip_open().

Later I also found x86_64 with emulator works just fine like arm64-v8a, but x86 fails again.
So I suspect this is some kind of 32/64 bit issues, but I couldn't figure out what exactly causing this problem.

I also tried a few other combinations with gcc toolchain and -D"CMAKE_C_FLAGS=-m32" but nothing worked for me.

Any helps?

(And to be clear, all above code snippets are from x86 setup, not successful ones with arm64 or x86_64.)

***EDIT***

I found a source of the problem so I want to share it here.

First off, I shouldn't have trusted Android native debugger.
As I mentioned above all parameters looked corrupted inside zip_open() but it was just debugger spitting out false information.
From there I wasted considerable amount of time to dig in wrong places like calling conventions etc.

The real source of problem was just one expression inside libzip source:

```
offset < ZIP_FSEEK_MIN
```

where "ZIP_FSEEK_MIN" is defined as -0x80000000L and "offset" was -65578 in my case.

Of course it should yield "false", but it wasn't in 32bit ABIs.
(Note that "offset" is zip_int64_t, which is 64bit interger in any platform.)

So I ran a few tests and result is:

```
offset < ZIP_FSEEK_MIN     // yield "true"
offset < -0x80000000L      // yield "true"
offset < -0x80000000LL     // yield "false"
offset < -0x80000000LL-1LL // yield "false"
offset < -0x80000000L+1L   // yield "true"
offset < -0x7fffffffL-1L   // yield "false", sometimes cause crash in armeabi
offset < -2147483648       // yield "false"
```

It seems -0x80000000L is a "bad form" to express minimum signed 32bit integer.
All std c library defines it as "-0x7fffffffL-1L" or "-2147483647i32 - 1".

There's also a horrible corner case where "-0x7fffffffL-1L" cause the program crash in armeabi (v7a and x86 are fine) but I couldn't find exact condition to trigger this. (And I'm not even sure how I should handle this.)

So that's it. Here's things I learned from this:

1. Try to avoid to compare something to "-0x80000000L".
2. Instead, use "-0x7fffffffL-1L" or something like that.
3. Don't trust android native debugger too much.
4. Thanks god armeabi only devices are not common anymore.

Thank you.

Comment: You are not expected to run **cmake** manually. You can simply reference the zlib **CMakeLists.txt** file in your **build.gradle**, and the library will be built correctly for all ABIs you want to use (I am not sure you need ALL). In your case, you only built the X86 library manually, but you cannot use it for other ABIs.

Comment: @AlexCohn Do you mean I should create a new android project just for libzip and point to the **CMakeLists.txt** shipped in **libzip repository** in the app's build.gradle, and build the project with android studio?

Comment: You can do it in the existing project. If you have native code that depends on lzip, your CMakeLists.txt can **include** theirs.

Comment: @AlexCohn OK I'll try it when I get home. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexCohn I tried add_subdirectory(libzip_src_dir, libzip_bin_output_dir) with weird result.

Comment: At first, zip_open() failed with x86 abi just like my previous attempt, but while I was desperately trying various combinations **there were some cases where zip_open() succeeds**.

I'm sure I'm not mistaken because it was on x86 only simulator and I confirmed 32bit pointer in the debugger. It was hard to find right environment but it seems it is somehow related with previous setup, so I think current android ndk build system might be buggy.

But all in all, add_subdirectory() in CMakeLists.txt of existing project doesn't ultimately solve the problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your project now builds and loads. You have a new problem: the runtime results are not what you expected. Make sure you don't use relative paths: in Android app, $PWD is the root directory.

Comment: I didn't use relative paths. This is what I tried: add_subdirectory( D:/Project/External/libzip  D:/Project/External/libzip/build )

Comment: So, when does zip_open() succeed and when it does not?

Comment: My project had built and loaded just fine. The problem was always libzip library don't behave correctly in runtime, only in 32bit ABIs.

Comment: @AlexCohn That thing is what I don't know haha. I'll try more tests tomorrow. I'll post any progress and thank you for your help!

Comment: @AlexCohn Just to be clear, 1) 64bit ABIs: always works fine. 2) 32bit ABIs, build manually as original post: zip_open() fails all the time. 3) 32bit ABIs, build in android studio (add_subdirectory()): zip_open() fails most of the time, but sometimes it succeeds. (I think it's inconsistency in compilation, not runtime)

Comment: Does it happen to #define __FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` or similar?

Comment: @AlexCohn I found what's causing the problem and edited the original post accordingly (see EDIT section above). Thanks for your help and interest!

Comment:  that's awesome! You should report the issue to libzip

Comment: Note that **clang** defines  `#define INT_MIN   (-__INT_MAX__  -1)`

Comment: I did report to libzip author and he already fixed the problem. :) (except for armeabi problem) [https://github.com/nih-at/libzip/commit/7d0f31327d70ba3e55db297d096af4](https://github.com/nih-at/libzip/commit/7d0f31327d70ba3e55db297d096af4)